# Control.MonadPlus.Free without unnecessary distribution

Tags: haskell, monads, free-monad, monadplus

I'm trying to use a free monad to build an EDSL for constructing AND/OR decision trees like Prolog, with `>>=` mapped to AND, and `mplus` mapped to OR.  I want to be able to describe something like `A AND (B OR C) AND (D OR E)`, but I don't want distributivity to turn this into `(A AND B AND D) OR (A AND B AND E) OR (A AND C AND D) OR (A AND C AND E)`.  Ultimately, I want to transform the AND/OR nodes into reified constraints in a constraint solver, without causing the combinatorial explosion in the number of alternatives that I want the solver to deal with.

In `Control.MonadPlus.Free`, `Plus ms >>= f` causes `f` to be applied to each of the `Pure` leaves under each monad in `ms`.  This is necessary because `f` may yield a different value for each `Pure` leaf that it replaces.

However, in `Plus ms >> g`, `g` cannot be affected by any of the leaves of `ms`, so distributing it over the `Plus` seems unnecessary.

Through trial and error, I found that I could extend the `Control.MonadPlus.Free` monad with a new `Then` constructor:

```
data Free f a = Pure a
              | Free (f (Free f a))
              | Then [Free f ()] (Free f a)
              | Plus [Free f a]
```

Here, the new `Then` constructor holds a sequence of monads whose value we ignore, followed by the final monad that yields the actual value.  The new `Monad` instance looks like:

```
instance Functor f => Monad (Free f) where
    return = Pure

    Pure a >>= f = f a
    Free fa >>= f = Free $ fmap (>>= f) fa
    Then ms m >>= f = Then ms $ m >>= f
    Plus ms >>= f = Plus $ map (>>= f) ms

    Pure a >> mb = mb
    Then ms ma >> mb = Then (ms ++ [ma >>= (const $ return ())]) mb
    ma >> mb = Then [] ma >> mb
```

The `>>` operator "caps" any existing leaves by replacing `Pure a` with `Pure ()`, appends the capped monad to the list, and replaces the value monad with the new one.  I'm aware of the inefficiency of appending the new monad with `++`, but I figure it's as bad as `>>=` stitching its new monad to the end of the chain with `fmap` (and the whole thing can be rewritten using continuations).

Does this seem like a reasonable thing to do?  Does this violate the monad laws (does this matter?), or is there a better way to use the existing `Control.Monad.Free`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at my [operational](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Operational) package, which is a different take on free monads.

In particular, have a look at the [BreadthFirstParsing.hs](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/operational/tree/master/doc/examples#example-code-for-the-operational-package) example. It features an `mplus` operation so that `>>=` does *not* automatically distribute over it. This allows you to implement parser combinators in a breadth-first fashion.

Translated to `Control.Monad.Free`, the point is that if you use the functor

```
data F b = MZero | MPlus b b
```

then `Free F` will automatically distribute `>>=` over `mplus`. You have to use the functor

```
data F b = MZero | forall a. MPlus (Free f a) (Free f a) (a -> b)
```

instead, if you want to implement a semantics for `MPlus` that does not automatically distribute `>>=`. (This is the main reason why I prefer my operational library over the free library.)