# How to encode actions that take monadic arguments with free (or freer) monads?

Tags: haskell, monads, free-monad, monadplus

Most monadic functions take pure arguments and return a monadic value. But there are a few that need also monadic arguments, for example:

```
mplus :: (MonadPlus m) => m a -> m a -> m a

finally :: IO a -> IO b -> IO a

forkIO :: m () -> m ThreadId

-- | From Control.Monad.Parallel
forkExec :: m a -> m (m a)
```

Each of them seems to bring up a different problem and I can't get a grasp of a generic way how to **encode such actions using free monads.**

- In both `finally` and `forkIO` the problem is that the monadic argument is of a different type than the result. But for *free* one would need them to be of the same type, as `IO a` gets replaced by the type variable of the encoding type, like `data MyFunctor x = Finally x x x`, which would only encode `IO a -> IO a -> IO a`.

  In [From zero to cooperative threads in 33 lines of Haskell code](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/06/from-zero-to-cooperative-threads-in-33.html) the author uses `Fork  next next` to fist implement

  ```
  cFork :: (Monad m) => Thread m Bool
  cFork = liftF (Fork False True)
  ```

  and then uses it to implement

  ```
  fork :: (Monad m) => Thread m a -> Thread m ()
  ```

  where the input and output have different types.
  But I don't understand if this was derived using some process or just an ad-hoc idea that works for this particular purpose.
- `mplus` is in particular confusing: a naive encoding as

  ```
  data F b = MZero | MPlus b b
  ```

  distributes over `>>=` and a [suggested better implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20376794/1333025) is more complicated. And also a native implementation of a free `MonadPlus` [was removed from *free*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32185389/1333025).

  In [freer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/freer-0.2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Freer.html#t:NonDetEff) it's implemented by adding

  ```
  data NonDetEff a where
    MZero :: NonDetEff a
    MPlus :: NonDetEff Bool
  ```

  Why is `MPlus` `NonDetEff Bool` instead of `NonDetEff a a`? And is there a way how to make it work with `Free`, where we need the data type to be a functor, other than using the [CoYoneda functor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17184834/1333025)?
- For `forkExec` I have no idea how to proceed at all.

Comment: It seems to me that the implementation depends not on the type of the function but on its semantics. "But I don't understand if this was derived using some process" I think the 'process' here is simply modelling your domain properly. For example, I think that the encoding of `finally` would be more obvious if you first try to encode the "most general" exception functions (`throw`, `catch`?). The type of `finally` is the same as `<*`.. so you theoretically there is no reason a function of this type can't be encoded (maybe just not directly..).

Comment: @user2407038 I understand what you mean. But I'm interested in the approach "mechanically encode the whole interface and let the interpreter worry about the implementation details".

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer only about the `Freer` monad part. Recall the definition:

```
data Freer f b where
    Pure :: b -> Freer f b
    Roll :: f a -> (a -> Freer f b) -> Freer f b
```

Now with

```
data NonDetEff a where
  MZero :: NonDetEff a
  MPlus :: NonDetEff Bool
```

we can define

```
type NonDetComp = Freer NonDetEff
```

When `Roll` is applied to `MPlus`, `a` is unified with `Bool` and the type of the second argument is `Bool -> NonDetEff b` which is basically a tuple:

```
tuplify :: (Bool -> a) -> (a, a)
tuplify f = (f True, f False)

untuplify :: (a, a) -> (Bool -> a)
untuplify (x, y) True  = x
untuplify (x, y) False = y
```

As an example:

```
ex :: NonDetComp Int
ex = Roll MPlus $ Pure . untuplify (1, 2)
```

So we can define a `MonadPlus` instance for non-deterministic computations

```
instance MonadPlus NonDetComp where
    mzero       = Roll MZero Pure
    a `mplus` b = Roll MPlus $ untuplify (a, b)
```

and run them

```
run :: NonDetComp a -> [a]
run (Pure x)       = [x]
run (Roll MZero f) = []
run (Roll MPlus f) = let (a, b) = tuplify f in run a ++ run b
```